# Create Desktop Sidebar Gadget using Swing

Tags: java, swing, windows-desktop-gadgets

I would like to create Gadget like [Window 7 Calendar gadget](http://wlcalendargadget.codeplex.com/).

[image]

Can I develop it using Java Swing or any other libraries or API's are available in Java for desktop gadget?

Comment: Looks like a translucent window.  What is special about it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, it will give you an idea about desktop widget creation

http://articles.carbonrider.com/2011/10/09/windows-7-your-own-desktop-gadget/

Update 2: The link has been changed to

http://www.carbonrider.com/2011/10/09/windows-7-your-own-desktop-gadget/

Comment: Your link demonstrates in images (and text) why pure J2SE is not going to be enough to to give the true Desktop gadget feel.  The [Windows Desktop Gadgets Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-desktop-gadgets/info) seems to have some good links as well.

Comment: Updated link with new reference.